# Java - Write content from one file chunk by chunk (e.g. 8 Bytes) alternately into multiple files

Tags: java, file, outputstream, fileoutputstream

So I've been trying to read the content of a text file and write the content chunk by chunk alternately into e.g. 2 new files.

I already tried multiple ways to do that but it won't work (OutputStream and FileOutputStream seems to be the most suitable).

Before i tried to part the file in e.g. 3 Parts and wrote the first part in one file, the second part in another and so on. Which worked perfectly fine with OutputStream and FileOutputStream.

But it won't work when i want to do it alternately.

To do it alternately i use the round robin algorithm, which on its own works fine.

I would be really thankful if you could show me some examples to do it!

```
public void splitFile(String filePath, int numberOfParts, long sizeOfParts[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    long bytes = 8;
    
    OutputStream partsPath[] = new OutputStream[numberOfParts];
    long bytePositition[] = new long[numberOfParts];

    long copy_size[] = new long[numberOfParts];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
        copy_size[i] = sizeOfParts[i];
        partsPath[i] = new FileOutputStream(path); //Gets Path from my Database (works)
        //System.out.println(cloudsTable.getCloudsPathsFromDatabase(i) + '\\' + name + (i + 1) + fileType);
    }

    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    while (true) {
        boolean done = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {

            if (copy_size[i] > 0) {
                done = false;
                if (copy_size[i] > bytes) {
                    copy_size[i] -= bytes;
                    bytePositition[i] += bytes;
                    
                    System.out.println("file " + i + " " + bytePositition[i]);
                    readWrite(file, bytePositition[i], partsPath[i]);
                } else {
                    bytePositition[i] += copy_size[i];
                    
                    System.out.println("rest file " + i + " " + bytePositition[i]);

                    readWrite(file, bytePositition[i], partsPath[i]);
                    copy_size[i] = 0;
                }
            }

        }


        if (done == true) {

            break;
        }

    }
    file.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < partsPath.length; i++) {
        partsPath[i].close();
    }

}

private void readWrite(InputStream file, long bytes, OutputStream path) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) bytes];
    while (file.read(buf) != -1) {
        path.write(buf);
        path.flush();
    }
```

}

What the code does is, it only write the content of the Originalfile in the first-copied file and the following files are empty

EDIT:
To clarify what the code should do is write the first 8 bytes to go to file 1, second 8 bytes to go to file 2, third 8 bytes to go to file 3, fourth 8 bytes to go to file 1, and so on, round robin, until file 1 is sizeOfParts[0] long, file 2 is sizeOfParts[1] long, and file 3 is sizeOfParts[2] long.

Comment: Show us the code you tried. Right now, this question looks like an attempt to trick us into writing your code for you.

Comment: I added it. Didn't know that asking a generell question would be interpreted as an attemp to trick..

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do here. 1) Why do you need `numberOfParts`? Isn't `sizeOfParts.length` the same thing? --- 2) What is the purpose of `sizeOfParts`? What is the effect on the result? --- 3) What is the purpose of `bytes`? What is the effect on the result?

Comment: Anyway, your code isn't working (whatever it's *trying* to do), because the `readWrite()` method is seriously flawed. You call `read(buf)`, but don't save the `len` return value, which is definitely needed for the `write(buf)` call, since that call should be `write(buf, 0, len)`. Also, the `readWrite()` will copy **all** of the input stream into the output stream, which means that the first output file ends up a copy of the input file, and the rest are just empty.

Comment: Okay, i tried to explain it, as good as i can:
1) numberOfParts is the number in how many the original file should be split into. E.g: 3 Parts
2) sizeOfParts is the byte-size each part should be. I calculate it dependend on the capacity of an Direcotory (which I set) and the size of the original file. E.g 1.File: 293 byte, 2.File: 323, 3.File 123. 
So that in each file alternatly a chunk (8bytes) will be written in, until the size of the part-file ist reached. Then the chunk will only be written in the left over parts.
3) bytes is size of a chunk that should be written in the Part-files

Comment: I just found out, that i should have do it with "path.write(buf, 0, (int) bytes);" but it still only copies the whole content into the first file.
Do you have any other hints? Or if not maby some Documentions? I am willing to find it out myself but i already looked up so many ways, and i cant get it right

Comment: So you want first 8 bytes to go to file 1, second 8 bytes to go to file 2, third 8 bytes to go to file 3, fourth 8 bytes to go to file 1, and so on, round robin, until file 1 is `sizeOfParts[0]` long, file 2 is `sizeOfParts[1]` long, and file 3 is `sizeOfParts[2]` long, and then what to do with the rest of the input file, i.e. what happens if `sum(sizeOfParts)` is not equal to the size of the input file? --- Please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: No, not `write(buf, 0, (int) bytes)`, but `write(buf, 0, len)`, like I already said!!! You write as many bytes as was read into the buffer, i.e. the number of bytes indicated by the **return value** of `read(buf)`, like I already said. That is why you need to save the return value, like I already said.

Comment: Unrelated: be consistent about following java naming rules. dont use the _ ... it should be copySize, not copy_size. And maybe it should say something that tells the reader what is going on with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the `readWrite()` method is only supposed to copy one 8-byte block of bytes, but has a loop that makes it copy all the remaining bytes in the input file.

In addition, the code should be enhanced to use `try-finally` to close the files, and to correctly handle end-of-file, in case the input file is shorter than the sum of parts.

I would eliminate the `readWrite()` method, and consolidate the logic to prevent duplicate code, like this:

```java
public void splitFile(String inPath, long[] sizeOfParts) throws IOException, SQLException {
    final int numberOfParts = sizeOfParts.length;
    
    String[] outPath = new String[numberOfParts];
    // Gets Paths from Database here
    
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream[] out = new OutputStream[numberOfParts];
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inPath));
        for (int part = 0; part < numberOfParts; part++)
            out[part] = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPath[part]));
        
        byte[] buf = new byte[8];
        long[] remain = sizeOfParts.clone();
        for (boolean done = false; ! done; ) {
            done = true;
            for (int part = 0; part < numberOfParts; part++) {
                if (remain[part] > 0) {
                    int len = in.read(buf, 0, (int) Math.min(remain[part], buf.length));
                    if (len == -1) {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    remain[part] -= len;
                    System.out.println("file " + part + " " + (sizeOfParts[part] - remain[part]));
                    out[part].write(buf, 0, len);
                    done = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        for (int part = 0; part < out.length; part++)
            if (out[part] != null)
                out[part].close();
    }
}
```